# Kubuntu installation with USB 3.0

Tags: dual-boot, usb, kubuntu

I am looking to buy a new laptop, and one I have been seriously considering is the Acer Nitro 5 (AN515-55). Most times it comes with preinstalled Windows, but for my studies I would need Dual Boot with Linux, preferably Kubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.

My question is regarding the installation, since this laptop model comes only with USB 3 ports and I have found several forum threads where people are describing problems with installing Ubuntu from USB 3 ports. However, most of these posts are several years old now, so I wanted to ask, if someone know whether these problems still exist.
Some specification of the laptop model in case it's needed:

Intel® Core™ i7 10750H processor

NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 graphic card

16 GB of RAM (although I would guess that this is not so important)

1000 GB SSD

3x USB 3.1 type-A Gen 1

Preinstalled Windows 10 Home 64 bit

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As someone who experienced** this in first hand, I'll try to explain some of the threads you might have encountered with (for Ubuntu 18.04.4 at least).

---

#### In short:

Some (but only few) **usb3 flash drive** models are indeed un-bootable and will not work when connecting to a **usb3 port**. It is not a computer hardware problem, rather than a flash device specific problem.

There is a small remark about this situation at the [Installation/FromUSBStick-old](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick-old) official documentation under the **Notes about bootability** section.

It may be solved when connecting the problematic device to a usb2 port, or using a usb hub (that has usb2 ports). Using a usb2 extender cable or an SD card also works. **Using a usb2 flash drive always works**.

---

**My own experience with this:**

It is noted (yet not fully documented) that some users like myself were not able to fully boot the ubuntu 18.04 live installer, or the installer froze while loading the OS when using a usb3 flash drive that was connected to a usb3 port. It had something to do with bad device drivers that the installer should contain, and using them to detect flash drives.

Strange as it is, this problem occurred only on specific usb3 flash drives model, and seems to be a manufacturer's specific design type or defect. Here is how I found out:

I create ubuntu flash drives regularly using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) for years now and did not encounter such problem  before. All of my machines (servers and workstations) use usb3 ports and never had any problems with my usb3 flash drives.

Our organization received a bulk order of two usb3 models: [SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 Flash Drive](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-ultra-usb-3-0#SDCZ48-128G-A46) 128GB, and [SanDisk Cruzer Glide 3.0 USB Flash Drive](https://shop.westerndigital.com/en-ap/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-cruzer-glide-usb-3-0#SDCZ600-064G-G35) 64GB, and I happen to need another live flash drive. I used the 128GB drive, and it actually did not work for me.

Thinking something gone wrong when creating the bootable DoK, I tried creating it again, and once again it failed to install. I also had my general use **Transcend usb3** flash drive with one of the partitions serving for live booting, so I decided to create it bootable with the same image with the same parameters and it worked!

I did the same with the SanDisk Cruzer glide (the 64GB) and it also worked. Unboxed another SanDisk Ultra 128GB and it failed.

Doing a little research afterwards showed me this is an actual on-going existing problem. Yet even after so many years and OS versions (not just Ubuntu family) the best solution for avoiding such devices is maintaining an online list of such bad models. The article I linked above does the same.

**It is still to be noted that such problem is not that common, and overall users should not be afraid of installing Ubuntu via usb flash drives.**

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer!
So you're saying, I can use any USB 2 device? That's interesting because I found that some people recommended not using a USB 2 drive in a USB 3 port.
I will let you know (or mark your answer as solution), as soon as I can confirm your experiences!

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to rate it. A usb2 device should be fine - every other solution suggested turns the usb3 device to a usb2 device in one way or another. Usb3 is fully backwards compatible with usb2: connecting a usb3 device to usb2 port makes the device to work as usb2, while a usb2 device connected to a usb3 port makes the host use the port as a usb2 port.